# All analytic functions $|f(z^2)|\geq |f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the analytic functions on the unit disk satisfying $|f(z^2)|\geq |f(z)|$ 
I need help for the problem. I guess we need to use Schwarz's lemma

Comment: Can you show that if $f$ is not constant, then $\lvert f\rvert$ has a local maximum at $0$?

Comment: $|\dfrac{f(z)}{f(z^2)}|<1$ on $\mathbb{D}$/

Comment: @MichaelLee I know that by maximal principle, |f| assumes its maximal on the boundary of D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show that $\lvert f(0)\rvert\geq \lvert f(z)\rvert$ for all $z$ in the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Consider $z\in \mathbb{D}$, and note that $z^{2^k}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$, as $\lvert z^{2^k}\rvert = \lvert z\rvert^{2^k}\to 0$ because $\lvert z\rvert < 1$. Then, as $f$ is analytic, $$\lim_{k\to \infty} f(z^{2^k}) = f(0)$$ As $\lvert f(z^{2^k})\rvert\geq \lvert f(z^{2^{k-1}})\rvert$ for all $k$, we have that $\lvert f(z^{2^k})\rvert$ increases monotonically (not necessarily strictly) to $\lvert f(0)\rvert$, so $\lvert f(0)\rvert\geq \lvert f(z)\rvert$. As this is true for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$, $f$ must be constant by the maximum modulus principle.

Answer (score 0):

From the given condition it follows that

$$\sup_{0\le |z|\le 1/2} |f(z)|\le\sup_{0\le |z|\le 1/2} |f(z^2)|=\sup_{0\le |z|\le 1/4} |f(z)|.$$

Thus $|f|$ has a local maximum in $\{0\le |z|\le 1/4\}.$ By the maximum modulus theorem, $f$ is constant in $D(0,1).$